# Captured photo is stretched with AVCaptureSession sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

IMPORTANT: if I use:     `session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;` my preview image is not stretched !! If I save the photo to the device `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);` the image is normal, only in the preview it is stretched.

I m using AVFoundation to capture photo.

```
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

CALayer *viewLayer = vImagePreview.layer;
NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = vImagePreview.bounds;
[vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
}
[session addInput:input];

stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
[session addOutput:stillImageOutput];
```

I set the sessionPreset to `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`:

```
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
```

My capture method:

```
-(void)captureNow {
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections)
    {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
        {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
            {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {
         CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
         if (exifAttachments)
         {
             // Do something with the attachments.
             NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
         } else {
             NSLog(@"no attachments");
         }

         NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
         NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(image.size));
         [self animateUpTheImageWithImage:image];


     }];

}
```

Where I add the captured photo's preview:

```
- (void) animateUpTheImageWithImage:(UIImage*)theImage{

    UIView* preview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height/*426*/)];
    CALayer *previewLayer = preview.layer;
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = previewLayer.frame;
    [previewLayer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;

    [self addSubview:preview];

}
```

And the result is my captured image is stretched !

[image: Capturing camera preview]

[image: Captured image preview]

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with AVCapture if the saved photo is not stretched. Have you thought about it?

Comment: Hey @incmiko did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem right now. Have been working on it all day and still have not found a way to fix it.

Comment: I answered my question, look at it below. I hope it will resolve your problem too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I resolved my problem. Here is the code what I'm using now, and it s working fine:

```
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

    captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = vImagePreview.bounds;
    [vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

    device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
```

...

```
stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
[session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

capturedImageView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.screenWidth,self.screenHeight)];
[self addSubview:capturedImageView];
```

and important the output imagaView:

```
vImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.screenWidth,self.screenHeight)];
    [capturedImageView addSubview:vImage];
    vImage.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
    vImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    vImage.image = theImage;
```

Some additional infos:

camera layer must be full screen ( You can modify its y coordinate but width and height must be full size ) and the outputImageView must be too.

I hope these will be useful infomations for somebody too.

Comment: what do you mean using vImage apple AVCam does not have this in sources?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];`

Comment: this doens't do anything, my preview is the same. session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh; working right with this. session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto; preview is bad

Comment: @incmiko Have you tried all the other types of `AVLayerVideoGravity` variable?

Comment: yes this method just work with preview of camera, the result will be saved stretched

Answer (score 0):

Change capture sessionPreset to AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540; and it works well for me.